# Spring resource bundle delimer

Tags: spring, localization, resources

We are using Spring LocaleChangeInterceptor and ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource for all our localization needs.  All is well until a strange requirement comes.

What the new requirement needs is that we have to allow each language property file to "float", which means that these resource bundles are no longer required to have all keys to be in sync.

Missing keys, in this use case, will have to default to use en_US properties. We have proposed to write tools to fill the missing keys with English messages, but that got push back hard from above. They say that it was doable in Struts and Spring should also do the same.

I have been searching up and down the web but I cannot find such example.  Can this even be done in Spring 3?

Comment: Does [Spring Manual Chapter 5.14.1. Internationalization using MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can extent class `ResourceBundle` and override its method `handleGetObject` like this:

```
    @Override
    public Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        try {
            return messages.getMessage(key, null, getLocale());
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
            return messages.getMessage(key, null, new Locale("en_US"));;
        }
    }
```

I did something very similar to his in my project. I also had to handle missing keys.

Comment: Both yours and gerrytan's will work well within objects.  In addition, what about <spring:message /> tag in JSP?  We can put a custom tag handler to spit out keys easily, but the keys themselves will have to know which language properties to use.  At the moment, I cannot make it work with Spring local context holder even the docs says so:  [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I can help with that. I use it in my JSF Spring project and it works with resource messages in my pages